# Help proving generalized Miller-Rabin Test

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please help me prove the following theorem below based off of Fermat's Little Theorem:

If $p$ is prime, and

$a^{(p-1)/q}$ $=$ $x$ $\pmod p$

where $q$ is a proper divisor of $p-1$ then,

$x^q$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod p$

Also, is the converse of this theorem true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend this:

> If $p$ is prime, $p \nmid a$ and

etc.. then, of course; this is merely re-stating [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) with an intermediate power identified as $x$.

The Miller-Rabin result mentioned in your title is stronger:

> If $p$ is an odd prime number, and $p – 1 = 2^sd$, with $d$ odd, then for every $a$ prime to $p$, either $ad ≡ 1 \bmod p$, or there exists $t$ such that $0 ≤ t < s$ and $a2^td ≡ −1 \bmod p$